# Запретить скрытие блока jQuery

Tags: jquery, блок, javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть блок .load раскрывается при клике по кнопке на пол страницы
Скрываю его так

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('.load, .load ul)) return;
        if ($('.load').is(':visible')) {
            // далее скрытие блока
        }
    });
```

Проблема в том что в блок подгружается контент и в нем могут идти различные html элементы, типа кнопок, картинок и т.д. Если кликнуть по ним, HTML код

```
<div class="load">
    <img src="">
    <input type="text" name="">
    // и так далее
</div>
```

Блок скрывается, перечислять все что может подгружаться в блок или в дальнейшем будет подгружаться

```
 if ($(e.target).is('.load, .load ul ..........)) return;
```

Раздуется на пол страницы.

Как можно обработать такие элементы и запретить скрытие блока если клик был произведен в блоке .load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто повесить обработчик событий для .load который будет делать e.stopPropagation();

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.load').hide();
});
$('#show').click(function(e) { //это кнопка которая показывает
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.load').show();
});
$(document).on('click','.load',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/HZ4Mz/

Answer (score 0):

А не проще-ли использовать модальные окна, например от Bootstrap? Уже готовые решения.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону функции toggle